# Android check resource exists?

Tags: android

I get my android resource like so:

```
    int mySound = (context.getResourceId("raw.mySound"));
```

Is there a way to check if the resource exists?

Thanks

Comment: I can't even find this method. It's not a member of Context. Please post valid code which you tested before posting it or ask differently...

Comment: @Knickedi getResourceId is a standard method on java.lang.String, I think poster has got something wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
if(mySound != 0)
```

means that it excist

Btw, there is no getResourceId in context http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Did you mean?  context.getResources().getIdentifier(...) ?

Comment: Context is a var, of type FREContext. context.getResources() does not work. Any ideas why?